# Including External plugins in Camunda

Tags: tomcat, camunda

I am trying to include some external plugins to my cockpit in Camunda. I have downloaded the war file for the same from [plugin store](http://camunda.org/plugins/) . Later I saved the war file in

> ...\CamundaHome\server\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps

folder on my system. Also, I tried saving it in

> ..\CamundaHome\server\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps\camunda-webapp-7.2.0-plugins\WEB-INF\lib folder.

I have restarted the server but the cockpit doesn't add the required plugins.
What more information do I need to add? 
Thanks.

Tomcat Server: 7.0.50

Camunda BPM: 7.2.0

PS: Above was the first stage of the problem. The real problem occurs during deployment. I have provided the solution in comment. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download the complete WAR from the Plugin Store you have to REPLACE the existing webapp under ..\CamundaHome\server\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps. So remove the original one there (which is deployed "exploded" - so it is the folder ..\CamundaHome\server\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps\camunda) before saving the new war to ..\CamundaHome\server\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps.

Then it should work.

Make sure that you create the WAR for Tomcat in the Plugin Store.

Cheers
Bernd

Comment: The problem was " validateJarFile(\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps\app\WEB-INF\lib\javaee-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2." while trying to deploy the new war.  Had to remove javaee-api.jar from WEB-INF\lib folder . This issue occurs if there exists multiple copies of jar with tomcat and application. It can also be resolved in maven by changing the scope as well . Thanks neverthless!! :)